# Unicode Problem in Codeblocks Win32 Dialog Project(SOLVED)

Tags: winapi, unicode, codeblocks

I am trying to make Unicode program(Persian) by CodeBlocks but it seems that is not easy Work!.

This is what I tried so far:

**First** I create Win32 GUI dialog Project and design resource by Resedit program.
I set encoding to UTF-8 in Resedit and in CodeBlocks(Setting->Editor>Encoding Setting) and set fonts to Tahoma(This Font include Persian characters).
In Resedit Preview and in CodeBlocks editor(when i open resource file) every thing show correctly, but when I compile project the characters show incorrect.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhhVV.jpg)   Resedit preview

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur0Ky.jpg)
Compiled

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include "resource.h"




//
// Dialog resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
DLG_MAIN DIALOG 0, 0, 186, 95
STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SETFONT | WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL
CAPTION "ثبت"
FONT 8, "Tahoma"
{
    PUSHBUTTON      "تایید", 0, 75, 40, 50, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "متن:", 0, 26, 20, 14, 9, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    EDITTEXT        0, 50, 20, 100, 14, ES_AUTOHSCROLL, WS_EX_LEFT
}



//
// Manifest resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
1                  RT_MANIFEST    ".\\manifest.xml"
```

Resource file code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "resource.h"

HINSTANCE hInst;

BOOL CALLBACK DlgMain(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
    }
    return TRUE;

    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
    }
    return TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}


int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    hInst=hInstance;
    InitCommonControls();
    return DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgMain);
}
```

Main.CPP(in CodeBlocks)

**Second** I create Win32Gui Frame Project in CodeBlocks and again try to build this window but this time i change something after google it.

```
 #if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
#define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
    #define UNICODE
#endif
    
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "commctrl.h"


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


wchar_t szClassName[ ] = L"CodeBlocksWindowsApp";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszArgument,
                     int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;               
    MSG messages;           
    WNDCLASSEXW wincl;        

    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);


    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                  

    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DFACE + 1);

    
    if (!RegisterClassExW (&wincl))
        return 0;


    hwnd = CreateWindowExW (
           WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL,                  
           szClassName,         
           L"ثبت",       
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       
           CW_USEDEFAULT,     
           285,                 
           183,                 
           HWND_DESKTOP,       
           NULL,               
           hThisInstance,     
           NULL                
           );

    
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);

 
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
      
        TranslateMessage(&messages);

        DispatchMessage(&messages);


    }


    return messages.wParam;
}




LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {


            HFONT hfont = CreateFont(-11, 0, 0, 0, 0, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ("Tahoma"));
            HWND btnhwnd = CreateWindowW(WC_BUTTONW, L"تایید", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP, 111, 65, 75, 23, hwnd,NULL, NULL, 0);
            SendMessageW(btnhwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, TRUE);
            HWND statichwnd = CreateWindowW( WC_STATICW, L"متن:", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_GROUP | SS_LEFT, 38, 33, 21, 15, hwnd, NULL, NULL, 0);
            SendMessageW(statichwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, TRUE);
            HWND edithwnd = CreateWindowW(WC_EDITW, L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 74, 33, 150, 23, hwnd, NULL, NULL, 0);
            SendMessageW(edithwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, TRUE);
        }
break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);      
            break;
        default:                     
            return DefWindowProcW (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For correctly show unicode characters i changed these items:

```
DefWindowProc to DefWindowProcW
SendMessage to SendMessageW
CreateWindow to CreateWindowExW
Char szClassName[ ] to  wchar_t szClassName[ ]
WNDCLASS wincl to  WNDCLASSEXW wincl
!RegisterClass (&wincl) to !RegisterClassExW (&wincl)
```

This functions/command support unicode but as you see these commands not exist on Win32 Dialog project!

After searching i found out it seems this lines on dialog project cause Unicode not show correctly:

```
  int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE 
                      hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
```

and

```
return DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL
```

I tried to make similar project in visual studio and see what visual studio do and can i do same in code blocks or not.

visual studio win32 dialog project cosist of resource file and main.cpp file that these are codes:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "resource.h"

#pragma comment(linker, \
  "\"/manifestdependency:type='Win32' "\
  "name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' "\
  "version='6.0.0.0' "\
  "processorArchitecture='*' "\
  "publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' "\
  "language='*'\"")

#pragma comment(lib, "ComCtl32.lib")

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(uMsg)
  {
  case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDCANCEL:
      SendMessage(hDlg, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
      return TRUE;
    }
    break;

  case WM_CLOSE:
    if(MessageBox(hDlg, TEXT("Close the program?"), TEXT("Close"),
      MB_ICONQUESTION | MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
    {
      DestroyWindow(hDlg);
    }
    return TRUE;

  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return TRUE;
  }

  return FALSE;
}

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE h0, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  HWND hDlg;
  MSG msg;
  BOOL ret;

  InitCommonControls();
  hDlg = CreateDialogParam(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, DialogProc, 0);
  ShowWindow(hDlg, nCmdShow);

  while((ret = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0) {
    if(ret == -1)
      return -1;

    if(!IsDialogMessage(hDlg, &msg)) {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
    // Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Persian (fa-IR) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_FAR)
LANGUAGE LANG_PERSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 223, 83
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL
CAPTION "ثبت"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "تایید",IDOK,85,49,50,14
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,61,28,98,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    LTEXT           "نام:",IDC_STATIC,46,31,12,8
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_DIALOG1, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 216
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 76
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // Persian (fa-IR) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

resource.rc

As you can see visual studio use below defination for winmain function:

```
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE h0, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

I tried to use visual studio source in codeblocks(copy-paste source code) for solving problem but codebloacks cant excute it and cause below error :

```
undefined reference to '_WinMain@16
```

I even tried to solve this error but i was unsuccessful and codeblocks crashed!
Also amazing error appeared in codeblocks when i set unicode to utf-16(the debug show #ifdef command has problem!)

Visual studio show correctly Unicode characters but code blocks cant.
What you think and suggest about my problem?
(thanks and sorry for my long question)

Comment: The route of least surprise: Set *everything* to use UTF-16.

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve]. Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. BTW, without knowing your (neither original nor mangled) strings: you face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Ø«Ø¨Øª'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `'ثبت'` and vice versa: `'ثبت'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'latin1')` -> `'Ø«Ø¨Øª'` …

Comment: How did you create the dialog? Did you use ansi or unicode win32 functions? For example do you use `GetMessageA` or just `GetMessage` with ansi enabled? I recommend to almost always use the unicode functions like `GetMessageW`. If you ever mix both variants in a bad way (even unintentionally) many things just break.

Comment: question edited and more detail added.

Comment: @HectorMoradi You don't have to change the default file encoding in codeblocks. You just have to ensure that resource.rc is encoded in UTF16-LE. Visual Studio does this automatically. Maybe you can copy the resource.rc from vs into your codeblocks project. As for the `_tWinMain` issue, you may use `wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int)`

Comment: @stuntman11,as  i said before when i use wWinMain then i  get "undefined reference to `WinMain@16'" error and when i save resource as unicode16 amazing error again hapeen.

Comment: A mojibake again: `'تایید'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1256')` returns `طھط§غŒغŒط¯`  what is your mangled string in blue border (disregarding RTL/LTR text direction.)

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching and trial/error finally, I solved the problem.

What I did:

- Save resource.rc file as UTF-8 Encoding
- Add `#pragma code_page(65001)` to the first line of the resource.rc file
- Use `DialogBoxW` instead of `DialogBox` function
- Use `MAKEINTRESOURCEW` instead of `MAKEINTRESOURCE`

And finally, all Unicode texts are displayed correctly.